# ADT Plugin 10.0.1 not working in Eclipse 3.6.2

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have installed the latest android sdk (android-sdk_r10-windows.zip), latest eclipse helios (eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.zip) and latest adt plugin (ADT-10.0.1.zip). Below is the listing for the installed packages of my android sdk:

- Android SDK Tools, revision 10
- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 3
- Documentation for Android SDK, API 11, revision 1
- SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 1
- Google USB Driver package, revision 4

I did also edit my Windows path environment variable to include the path to adb.exe and set my android sdk location in eclipse preferences accordingly.

Everything looks perfect until I try to import a sample project (by phonegap). There is a console message telling "Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'".

I have been googling around since yesterday. I just wonder if anyone did manage to get all these (eclipse 3.6.2, android sdk r10, adt 10.0.1) click together.

By the way, I find that there is also no way for us to fall back to earlier combination of eclipse, android sdk, and adt plugin. In my case, I managed to get an earlier android sdk (android-sdk_r09-windows.zip) and adt 9. But when I tried to install the basic packages online, I was hit by this error:

"Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Connection timed out: connect"

Earlier android sdk and adt plugin is not available; latest android sdk and adt plugin is not capable.

Many thanks for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got all these click together already. It is actually due to the antivirus/firewall program. It is indeed nothing wrong with eclipse, adt plugin or android sdk. Just make sure that android executables is not blocked from running. Anyway, big thanks to those contributed to this post.

Answer (score 2):

Start Here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Head over to the installing URL: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Look at the path for the download: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip

Substitute the version you want in that link:

ADT 10.0.1: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip

ADT 10.0.0: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.0.zip

ADT 9.0.0 (Dead Link): http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-9.0.0.zip

ADT 9.0.0: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT_9.0.0.zip

ADT 8.0.1: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.1.zip

ADT 8.0.0: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.0.zip

ADT 0.9.9: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.9.zip

ADT 0.9.8: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.8.zip

ADT 0.9.7: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.7.zip

ADT 0.9.6: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.6.zip

ADT 0.9.5: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.5.zip

ADT 0.9.4: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.4.zip

Given that the 9.0.0 link swapped a '-' for a '_' in the path, it looks like some poor soul is doing these builds by hand.  Too bad directory browsing isn't available for these.  Anyway, hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml and try again.

You can check the project you are trying to import for settings which are not campatible with your Eclipse or SDK version.

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @logitab Sometimes I can download the SDK only from https and sometimes from http. The advice comes from google to change it if you can`t download the SDK. But this does not resolve the other issue.

Comment: I have no problem with the latest adt plugin url. But it is just not working. I get the same console message complaining about the failure of parsing adb version the moment I set my sdk location in eclipse. I just wonder if the earlier adt plugin url or jar file still available. This latest adt plugin is indeed a real pain...

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse version should be fine. You should focus on the SDK version. many have had trouble on Windows with rev 10. You can install and use all the previous versions of Android SDK easily as long as the url you're using is correct.

Comment: Are you referring to the adt plugin url? The problem is it seems that the URL provided is meant for the latest adt plugin. I would appreciate if anyone can provide me with urls for earlier adt plugin.